# Formatting Datetime Column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a table called FcData and the data looks like:

```
Op_Date  

2011-02-14 11:53:40.000 
2011-02-17 16:02:19.000 
2010-02-14 12:53:40.000 
2010-02-17 14:02:19.000
```

I want the output in the mm/yyyy format sample output should be:

```
Op_Date

02/2011
02/2011
02/2010
02/2010
```

I wrote query like :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(mm,Op_Date
)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,Op_Date))
 FROM Fcdata
```

But I am getting output as:

```
Op_Date

2/2011
2/2011
2/2010
2/2010
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Best option is to return the full value to the client and let the client code format it. Any reason you have to do it in the DB?

Comment: @Oded I am joining this data to another table in which they stored the format as 02/2011 instead of 2/2011

Comment: What is the type of the join column in the other table?

Comment: @oded The column in the other table is Month_year and it is of varchar data type

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for, but I would say the varchar column needs to be changed to a DateTime or Date (SQL Server 2008) column.

Comment: Not helping here - but [SQL Server "Denali" will have a `FORMAT` function - finally!](http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/08/sql-server-denali-format-most-wanted.html)

Comment: I blogged about FORMAT here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/08/09/sql-server-v-next-denali-ctp3-t-sql-enhancements-format.aspx Also as an aside, please don't use VARCHAR without length. For background see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is about the shortest code you'll find, and only requires one conversion:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), Op_Date, 103), 7);
```

Mapping it to your query:

```
SELECT Op_Date, RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), Op_Date, 103), 7)
    FROM dbo.Fcdata;
```

And the join would be:

```
SELECT f.*, o.*
    FROM dbo.Fcdata AS f
    INNER JOIN dbo.OtherTable AS o
    ON RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(10), f.Op_Date, 103), 7) = o.column_name;
```

Just don't expect performance to be snappy if the table is large, because the convert is going to force SQL Server to scan every single row.

Also please don't use shorthand like yyyy and mm. Do you know that y and yyyy are different? And that there are now FIVE different shorthands that start with m (m, mi, ms, mm, mcs)? Spell it out. If you mean YEAR, say YEAR. Then it's clear to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(mm,Op_Date)) = 1 THEN
    '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(mm,Op_Date)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,Op_Date))
  ELSE
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(mm,Op_Date)) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,Op_Date))
  END
FROM Fcdata
```

Comment: 5 converts? Seems quite wasteful to do the case when you can just always append the 0 and take the right. Then at least you only have 2 converts.

Comment: LOL..yes was looking at the your solution and definitely, "hats off to you".  Your solution is much much more elegant.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MM, Op_Date)), 2) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(yyyy,Op_Date))
```